# document.querySelector("foreignObject") is null in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, svg, css-selectors

Working with embedded SVG in HTML5 I've found strange behavior in Chrome browser. (http://jsfiddle.net/complynx/htp4hqe2/)

For example, in the following `html/svg` code:

```
<svg>
    <foreignObject>
        <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <div>foo</div>
        </body>
    </foreignObject>
</svg>
<script>
    var T=document.querySelector("foreignObject");
</script>
```

Variable `T` will be null in Chrome (for Firefox works fine).
Any other selectors, even for contents of `<foreignObject>` work fine.

Is there any tag-specific selector in Chrome for this case?

**Upd**:
As **Rob W** mentioned in comments, there is a [known bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=286677) in WebKit.

Comment: IE does even worse, but IE has never been the best when it comes to SVG anyways. Still, this is very reminiscent of IE's history of failing to parse unrecognized elements.

Comment: Known bug: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=286677

Answer (score 0):

Simple, yet in some cases not good workaround.

```
<svg>
    <foreignObject class="ForeignObjectStubClass">
        <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <div>foo</div>
        </body>
    </foreignObject>
</svg>
<script>
    var T=document.querySelector(".ForeignObjectStubClass");
</script>
```

Using CSS class instead of tag name is enough

Comment: Your question asks for a "tag specific selector". This is tag agnostic.

Comment: I know. This answer is not the best for this case. But still someone could find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Edit, Updated

Try

```
var _T = document.getElementsByTagName("foreignObject");
// select `DIV` element within `_T` `HTMLCollection`
var filtered = _T[0].children.item("DIV");
console.log(filtered);
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/htp4hqe2/2/

See [ParentNode.children](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode.children) , [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) ; see also [NodeFilter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeFilter)

Comment: And what if composite selector is needed?

Comment: Not certain what "composite selector" is ? If possible , can illuminate ? Thanks

Comment: for example "foreignObject div" in the above code to select inner div items.

Comment: For this particular case You're right. But what about any other case. There is a plenty of situations where the reference to the tag can occur. Especially with new CSS3 selectors.

Comment: @complynx Not certain about meaning of "any other case" ? There could be infinite possibilities of possible tags. Authors could define a `DTD` for that specific page , with a variation of custom markup. See , at OP "Is there any tag-specific selector in Chrome for this case?" . Piece should achieve same result for other tags ; could try different selectors at jsfiddle ? Perhaps , edit OP to include requirement for "any case" ? , or define / re-define the `tag` cases / multiple selectors ; included at original post ? Thanks

Comment: Try http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/htp4hqe2/3/ , utilizing `class` selector . Thanks